# App Generator: How can I declare a variable for use in the entire generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-generation

I have a rails app generator and I need to sanitize `app_name` in a few locations throughout my templates. It feels wrong to do it in every single spot that the `sanitized_app_name` is needed but I am having a hard time finding documentation on this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a constant:

```
APP_NAME = ->(input) { ...sanitizing code ... }.(:real_app_name)
```

and use it everywhere.

Comment: This is definitely the sort of route I want to take - but where do I define that?

I have placed it inside ruby script in `bin/` that calls `AppGenerator.start` but I get a (erb):4:in `template': uninitialized constant DefaultRails::AppGenerator::DB_NAME (NameError)

Comment: It’s hard to tell since I have no idea about your project structure. Put it e.g. in your `AppGenerator` class.